# running flash file on android 4.0 but only sound is comming with white screen!

Tags: webview

i have a problem to run flash file on android 4.0, I used intent but nothing happened and now i am using web view to run but only sound is coming and only white screen is on display. 
  please help me to solve my problem, i am stuck here and i am in big trouble. below is my code that i used.

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


    String html = "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///sdcard/mainV7.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///sdcard/mainV7.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
    String mimeType = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that development questions are off topic here (see [FAQ]). You might want to ask a moderator (using the "flag" link) to migrate it to e.g. StackOverflow, where our Enthusiast Developers are.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link : [Flash Support for Android](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406507,00.asp)

Also check whether your device supports flash file or not.